# Cannot install Composer

Tags: macos, terminal, composer-php, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to install Composer on OSX High Sierra.

Following the instructions on https://getcomposer.org/download/, I execute this in Terminal:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
```

This takes a long time (1 minute maybe) and then gives me the following error:

```
Warning: copy(https://getcomposer.org/installer): failed to open stream: Operation timed out in Command line code on line 1
```

Any clues what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is going on, but consider using Homebrew to install `composer`.

First install Homebrew, then run

```
$ brew install composer
```

For reference, see https://brew.sh.